# How can I make Visual Studio open tabs always in its main window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a multi-monitor system, and Visual Studio set up like this:[image]

The main windows on the left, stuff like Solution Explorer, Output and Error windows on the right. When I want to open any file from the second monitor, the new tab also gets opened there. However, I rather want new tabs to appear in the tab well on my main monitor. Is there any setting (or extension) that can achieve that?

Comment: what extensions do you currently have installed?

Comment: @Dennis Resharper, CodeMaid, PInvoke, Productivity Power Tools, XAML Regions, XAML Styler, Infragistics, IndentGuide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what causing it. Resharper and Productivity Power Tools both have an influence on how your document windows are managed.

A few options:

- Try dragging the new window that is opening on the wrong screen and dock it; VS might remember this.
- Check/review all the options for Resharper and the Productivity Power Tools.
- Check that you don't have any additional R# extensions installed.
- Export your current settings and reset your environment.
- Disable extensions one at a time. A common approach to solving a problem by stripping things back until it works again.

I remember having some problems years ago when I ran a multi-monitor setup (at one stage 3+ screens), however now I do all development on a Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Resetting the environment somehow did the trick. I thought this was a "feature" rather than misbehaviour.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help.