# How declare default opened windows in multiple windows when new instance are opened in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Example:
Main VisualStudio Window:
[image: Main VisualStudio Window]

When Im moving the Tab to the New windows:

[image: When Im moving the Tab to the New windows]

Then open an new Instance from Solution Explorer, Its always openning them in new windows instead of Main windows.

I want it instances was always opened in Main Windows.How?

I search on google and baidu , this is only what I found:

[How can I make Visual Studio open tabs always in its main window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919267/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-open-tabs-always-in-its-main-window)

As the accepted answer, how to reset IDE? Is it mean to uninstall VS and install it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Reset IDE Layout by :

Windows > Reset Layout